# jQuery calculate sum text fields if checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to calculate the sum of text fields from a row which are checked.

My code works fine, but the problem which I am facing is my only calculate the value of first row only and it to previous result every time instead of adding current text field value.

Here is working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/infohassan/27L6wvgw/

Here is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $checkboxes = $('input[name^="txtChecked"]');
  $checkboxes.change(function() {
    $('input[name^="txtChecked"]').each(function() {
      var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
    calculateTotal();
    });
  });
});


function calculateTotal() {
  var total = 0;    
    $('input[name^="txtChecked"]:checked').each(function(){
      var val = parseFloat($('input[name^="txtCostAmount"]').val());
      total += val;
    });

  $('input[name="txtNetAmount"]').val(total);
}
```

Comment: do you want the sum to get updated if the user enters a new value in textbox ?

Comment: yes of course i want new values if user enters into it

Comment: `$('input[name^="txtCostAmount"]')` returns 3 elements, but .val() (as per the documentation) will only return the value of the first one it finds. You need a way to associate the checkbox with the textbox (`data-` attributes might be a good way, or classes) then the code can isolate the correct related checkbox.

Comment: Yes but if I use `data-` attribute I can only calculate with the default value if user inputs in textbox it won't be added

Comment: no, you would use the data-attribute to link the two controls (checkbox and textbox) to each other, not to store the value. That way when you find a checkbox that's checked, you know which textbox to use to get the next value to add to the total by looking at the data- attribute, which would contain the id of the textbox. The answer below uses a similar principle except relying on the relative positions of the controls within the markup, which works but might break if you change the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cleaned your event handler...
And I made the `.each()` loop look for the text input which is on the same `tr` as the checkbox...

[**UpdatedFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/qr95zb2r/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $checkboxes = $('input[name^="txtChecked"]');
  $checkboxes.change(function() {
    //$('input[name^="txtChecked"]').each(function() {
      //var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
      calculateTotal();
    //});
  });
});


function calculateTotal() {
  var total = 0;    
  $('input[name^="txtChecked"]:checked').each(function(){
    var val = parseFloat($(this).parents("tr").find('input[name^="txtCostAmount"]').val());
    total += val;
  });

  $('input[name="txtNetAmount"]').val(total);
}
```

Comment: wow great it works and resolve my biggest issue thanks really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var $checkboxes = $('input[name^="txtChecked"]');
$checkboxes.change(function() {
      //  var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.find(':checked').length;      
  calculateTotal();
  });
});


function calculateTotal() {
 var total = 0;    
    $('input[name^="txtChecked"]:checked').each(function(index, item){
    var parent = $(item).closest('tr');
  var val = parseFloat(parent.find('input[name^="txtCostAmount"]').val());
  total += val;
    });
    
 $('input[name="txtNetAmount"]').val(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Items</th>
<th>Cost</th>
</thead>

<tbody>
</tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="txtChecked0" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Item Name 1</td>
        <td><input class="form-control input-sm" name="txtCostAmount0" value="3500" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td><input name="txtChecked1" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Item Name 2</td>
        <td><input class="form-control input-sm" name="txtCostAmount1" value="4500" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td><input name="txtChecked2" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Item Name 3</td>
        <td><input class="form-control input-sm" name="txtCostAmount2" value="4500" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p>NetAmount <input class="form-control" name="txtNetAmount" value="0.00" readonly="" type="text"></p>
```